# how to add hibernate query results in to array list

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, datatable

my task was to populate prime faces data tables with data values from hibernate.we can fetch all the record in the table by this query

```
select from employee
```

will fetch all the records from the table employee ,employee field has two fields name,aage
the hibernate query for converting it to list was

List list =query.list();
i want to convert it in to array list having two fields name,age with all objects from hibernate

then populate the data table with

```
#{}
```

can any one explain with example

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch employee table data in this way
Here hibernateSession is the reference variable of Session.

```
List employees=hibernateSession.createQuery("from Employee").list();
```

Than through while loop you can get your data

```
    Employee employee;
    int x=0;
    while(x<employees.size())
    {
    employee=(Employee)employees.get(x);
    String name=employee.getName());
    int age=employee.getAge();
    x++;
}
```

Hope this helps if you think that this solves your problem than mark the answer as solution

Comment: can we populate datatable with raw list

Comment: Can you please show me sample output you want as i am not getting, Exactly what you want to do?

Comment: this is a prime faces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml here they have populated the datatable with values with array list they have created . i want to populate it with list values got from hibernate

Comment: Thanks for demo. As i had never used PrimeFace framework actually i ain't heard of it. Currently i am looking into it, if i get it then for sure i'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

To put the data into an `ArrayList`, you can use this [ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)):

`ArrayList list = new ArrayList(query.list());`